# Extracting strings from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I print only the "mid" or the "status" in this list of dictionaries?

---

```
list = [{'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6269'}, {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6270'},{'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6271'}, {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6272'}, {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6273'}, {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6274'},{'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6288'}, {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6289'}]
```

---

I tried : `print list[0]['mid']` but it is only giving the 'mid' value for the first item in the list? How can i do it for the whole `list` ?

Comment: Using `list` as variable will shadow the built-in method `list()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
data = [{'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6269'},
        {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6270'},
        {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6271'},
        {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6272'},
        {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6273'},
        {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6274'},
        {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6288'},
        {'status': 'OK', 'mid': '6289'}]

print [item['mid'] for item in data]
```

PS: don't name your variables `list`, you cannot use the built-in `list` then.

Comment: thank you, for your answer, but what do you mean by do not call variables list ?

Comment: Don't use names like `list` for your own stuff, call your list `mylist`, or `thelist`, `data`, or better yet, a name actually describing what's inside.

Comment: ah okay i get it. 
and how to skip the error 'NoneType' Object is unsibscriptable because i've tried what u told me on myList which is bigger and it returns this error : /

Comment: You'll have to show what you've tried exactly. Are there `None`s in your list?

Comment: yeah there's some None values i'll use filter(None,myList) it should work =)

Comment: You can filter right in the comprehension: `[item['mid'] for item in data if item]`

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answer is correct, i will try and explain why OP's original code won't work.

1. Firstly name of the variable. A comment on the original question explains it well enough
2. You say why print list[0]['mid'] only gives the first value. The reason is that you are only giving list[0], which is a dictionary containing two keys, status and mid and you are trying to get the value corresponding to the "mid" key which will be a single value

If you haven't worked with List Comprehensions before you could do with a simple for loop, which ranges from 0 to length of your list. Or use for item in list type of iteration.